# Is the transition epithelium a monolayer epithelium? Or is it a stratified epithelium?

Tags: histology

I had learned that transitional epithelium is a type of pseudostratified epithelium, so I understood that transitional epithelium is a type of monolayer epithelium.

Wikipedia has the following description(but with source tag);

” These structural elements cause the epithelium to allow distension; however, these also cause the tissue to be relatively fragile and, therefore, difficult to study. All cells touch the basement membrane.[citation needed]”
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epithelium

From the above description, all　epithelial cell appears to be in directly adhered with the basement membrane.

However, the illustration in the Wikipedia entry for Epithelium is clearly multi-layered. Thus, it appears to be a stratified epithelium.

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/64/423_Table_04_02_Summary_of_Epithelial_Tissue_CellsN.jpg/900px-423_Table_04_02_Summary_of_Epithelial_Tissue_CellsN.jpg

So, I would like to identify which is correct;

> Is the transition epithelium a monolayer epithelium? Or is it a stratified epithelium?

Comment: Urothelium, which is another way to refer to transitional epithelium is indeed a stratified epithelium.